# Get Gradle build script repositories by name in other gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, build-script

My gradle project structure is like so:

```
project
│   gradle.properties
│   build.gradle    
│
└───common-config
    │   common-buildscript.gradle
    │   common-java.gradle
```

File contents:

**gradle.properties**

```
artifactory_user=username
artifactory_password=password
```

**common-buildscript.gradle**

```
def properties = new Properties()
file("../gradle.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }

repositories {
    maven {
        url "someRepo1.com"
        credentials {
            username = properties.get("artifactory_user")
            password = properties.get("artifactory_password")
        }
        name = "Some Repo 1"
    }
    maven {
        url "someRepo2.com"
        credentials {
            username = properties.get("artifactory_user")
            password = properties.get("artifactory_password")
        }
        name = "Some Repo 2"
    }
}
```

**common-java.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("Some Repo 1")
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("Some Repo 2")
}
```

Upon running **gradle clean build**, I've got the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Repository with name 'Some Repo 1' not found.
```

It seems that, in **common-java.gradle**, gradle is not able to detect "Some Repo 1" name in **common-buildscript.gradle**. However this will work if I put the contents of both files in the same **build.gradle**

The reason I want to do this is I want to apply the common build script to many other build scripts in my repos.

Please kindly advice how I can resolve this. Thank you

**Update**

**build.gradle** content:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        commonConfig = rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath
    }
    apply from: "${commonConfig}/common-config/common-buildscript.gradle", to: buildscript
}

apply from: "${commonConfig}/common-config/common-java.gradle"
```

Comment: How do you call your common-buildscript.gradle and common-java.gradle files, in which closure and in which order?

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan Updated build.gradle file content. I apply `common-buildscript.gradle` first in the `buildscript` block. Then outside, I apply `common-java.gradle`